# usmap not showing data for some Alaska counties

Tags: r, maps

I am plotting obesity values for counties in Alaska, but some counties are grey, and not representing the values for that county. I am not able to figure out the FIPS codes for the counties that are grey, or why they are grey. I assume the FIPS codes I have for them are incorrect, but even the internal upmaps population data shows them as grey.

```
# read in data
chd_map = read.csv(file = 
'https://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/media/document/analytic_data2022.csv', 
header = TRUE, sep=",")

# pull out FIPS codes and obesity values
chd_map = chd_map[-c(1,2),c(3,75)]

# make obesity values numeric
chd_map$Adult.obesity.raw.value = as.numeric(chd_map$Adult.obesity.raw.value) * 100

# rename fips column
colnames(chd_map)[1] = 'fips'

# plot data
plot_usmap(
  data = chd_map,
  size = 0.1,
  regions = "counties",
  include = c('AK'),
  values = "Adult.obesity.raw.value",
  color = "black") +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis", name = "Percentage of Adults with Obesity (2022)", label = scales::comma
  ) +
  labs(title = "Figure X. Distribution of Obesity Prevalence by County") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(color = "white", fill = "white"), legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image: Figure showing grey counties]

Comment: There is are no matches and no data for these two counties in your dataset. To get the county codes and names you could do `alaska <- us_map(regions = "counties", include = "AK"); dplyr::anti_join(alaska, chd_map, by = "fips") |> dplyr::count(fips, county)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding the names to the missing counties (Chugach Census Area [02063] &  Copper River Census Area [02066], I found out that these counties were created in 2019. The Valdez-Cordova Census Area county was split in 2019 into these two new counties, and my data was created pre-2019, so it still had the Valdez-Cordova Census Area county. I ended up creating Chugach Census Area &  Copper River Census Area in the data with the same values as Valdez-Cordova Census Area.

```
valdez_obesity = chd_map$Adult.obesity.raw.value[chd_map$fips == '2261']

chugach = data.frame(2063,valdez_obesity)
names(chugach) = c('fips', 'Adult.obesity.raw.value')

copper = data.frame(2066,valdez_obesity)
names(copper) = c('fips', 'Adult.obesity.raw.value')

obesity_map_data = rbind(obesity_map_data, chugach, copper)

obesity_map_data = obesity_map_data[-which(obesity_map_data$fips == 2261),]

plot_usmap(
  data = chd_map,
  size = 0.1,
  regions = "counties",
  include = c('AK'),
  values = "Adult.obesity.raw.value",
  color = "black") +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis", name = "Percentage of Adults with Obesity (2022)", label = scales::comma
  ) +
  labs(title = "Figure X. Distribution of Obesity Prevalence by County") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(color = "white", fill = "white"), legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image: fixed_map]